# Firebase Query Equal To Multiple Values

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to use a firebase filter like the one called queryEqualTo() but I need to be able to filter to multiple things such as queryEqualTo("Science", "English")

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A Firebase Database query can only contain one orderBy statement and condition. Often you can accomplish the user-case by modeling your data differently, but it's hard to give more specific answer without more information in your question (e.g. a sample of the JSON data, as text - no screenshots). For a general introduction, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/), view [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and read http://stackoverflow.com/q/26700924.

Comment: This video might help https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=9m5s